# Ng-switch vs ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-template, ng-switch

I have a web application and it will be dynamic, I just have to create a template and then I will retrieve data with json. In particular I will have these cards:

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="landing">
    <section id="intro">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <!-- Cards -->
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="riga">
            <div class="r2">
              <div class="r4">
                <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                  <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                      <div class="cover">
                        <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb2.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="user">
                        <img src="img/img1.png" class="img-circle" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                          <p class="profession">Text</p>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                    Info
                                                </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                      <div class="header">
                        <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Back  
                                            </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="r4">
                <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                  <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                      <div class="cover">
                        <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="user">
                        <img src="img/img2.png" class="img-circle" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                          <p class="profession">Text</p>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                   Info
                                                </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                      <div class="header">
                        <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Back  
                                            </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="r4">
                <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                  <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                      <div class="cover">
                        <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb2.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="user">
                        <img src="img/img3.png" class="img-circle" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                          <p class="profession">Text</p>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                    Info
                                                </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                      <div class="header">
                        <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Back  
                                            </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end inner -->
    </section>
  </body>

</html>
```

I will have N cards, and all will have their own text. What is the best solution to create them dynamically? I thought to call before the data, then create a card for each of json string. What is the best technique? Use ng-repeat or ng-switch?

Comment: Storing data in the scope of an angular controller and using ng-repeat over this scope array would be the solution here.

Comment: ng-switch would be more for if you had one object coming in that needed different UIs based on its properties. In your case, since you have an array of several objects (your cards) that are seemingly the same, you would use ng-repeat to display them. Of course, if your cards have different layouts depending on their types, you could use ng-switch inside ng-repeat.